# Trouble making POST request to docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask

I have 2 dockerized flask applications, applications can be accessed on the following addresses

***App #1***

```
0.0.0.0:5001 [GET]
0.0.0.0:5001/ep [POST]
```

***App #2***

```
0.0.0.0:6004 [GET]
0.0.0.0:6004/ep [POST]
```

`App #2` make post request to `App #1` on `0.0.0.0:5001/ep` address

Issue is that I can easily make GET requests to both Apps and I can also make POST request to `App #2` successfully but `App #2` cannot make POST request to `App #1` at `0.0.0.0:5001/ep` (error mentioned below) even though containers are running without any errors

> ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001): Max retries exceeded with url: /ep (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f520531ca90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Below is the code for Flask Applications `app.py`

**App #1**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify('App1')

@app.route('/ep', methods = ['POST'])
def ep():

    data = {}

    # code for receiving data
    # processing data and saving results in dictionary 

    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

**App #2**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify('App2')

@app.route('/ep', methods = ['POST'])
def ep():
    
    data = {}

    res = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:5001/ep', files = data)
    res = res.json()

    return jsonify(data) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Any advice will be very helpful

Comment: Show how one of your apps connect to another and also show how you start your containers.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Hello I am running them as independent containers, here are some docker files and commands I am using https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uitb6n1l0nbritk/AAD6kxDnjihSrS8oIFIlUXLya?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have few of conceptual misunderstanding here:**

1. When you bind your service to `0.0.0.0` that does not mean you can connect to that service using ip address `0.0.0.0`. This only means the service accepts connections through all the network interfaces your "box" has.
2. In order to connect containers over the network they has to be within the same non-default network (better to use non-default because default does not support service lookup by name)
3. When you establish a connection from container to another container you should use container port, not the host port
4. **(*)** I didn't manage to run app2 without adding `requests` to `requirements.txt`

**So the steps to fix are:**

0. Fix your `requirements.txt` for app2
1. Create the network: `docker network create flasktest`
2. Fix your app2 code to be:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify('App2')

@app.route('/ep', methods = ['POST'])
def ep():
....
    data = {}

    res = requests.post('http://my-target-host:5000/ep', files = data)
    res = res.json()

    return jsonify(data).

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

3. Build your images
4. Start your app1 container: `docker run -p 5001:5000 --net flasktest --name my-target-host app1`
5. Start your app2 container: `docker run -p 5002:5000 --net flasktest app2`

**Test your post using:** `curl -X POST localhost:5002/ep`

Comment: Hello Alexey I created a new virtual network with the command you mentioned and ran all containers on that network but the same error appears

Comment: I have added some imports that I forgot please check the updated post

Comment: Thanks for putting efforts to write the detailed answer, issue is fixed